# VPN netmap multiple sites with same LAN network address

Tags: linux, iptables, vpn, routing, nat

I have some issues applying netmapping to a case for which I could not find much info about on the web.
I am trying to set up a VPN network (server ip: 10.1.0.1) where a user (VPN IP: 10.1.0.2) can connect to multiple sites (in this example just two: A and B) with the same LAN IP:

- Site A has the following network setup:
  VPN-IP: 10.1.1.1
  Network address: 192.168.1.0/28
  Netmapped address: 10.2.0.0/28
- Site B has the following network setup:
  VPN-IP: 10.1.1.2
  Network address: 192.168.1.0/28
  Netmapped address: 10.2.0.16/28

My current setup:

- iptables rule in mangle to mark packets based on their netmapped IP-Address. Packets for A are marked with 0x20000 and packets for B are marked with 0x20010.

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i tun0 -s 10.1.0.0/24 -d 10.2.0.0/16 -j IPMARK --addr=dst --and-mask=0x7FFFF0
```

- iptables rule in nat prerouting to do the netmapping. 10.2.0.0/28 is mapped to 192.168.1.0/28 and 10.2.0.16/28 is mapped to 192.168.1.16/28.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i tun0 -s 10.1.0.0/24 -d 10.2.0.0/28 -j NETMAP --to 192.168.1.0/28
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i tun0 -s 10.1.0.0/24 -d 10.2.0.16/28 -j NETMAP --to 192.168.1.0/28
```

- iptables rule in forward to forward packages inbound on tun0 and outbound on tun0

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
```

I also have forward rule for RELATED, ESTABLISHED.

- routing rules to use tables for packets marked with 0x470000 and 0x470030:

```
32762:  from all fwmark 0x20000 lookup table0.out
32765:  from all fwmark 0x20010 lookup table1.out
```

- routing tables look like this:

```
default via 10.1.1.1 dev tun0 table table0.out 
default via 10.1.1.2 dev tun0 table table1.out
```

- reverse path filtering is set to 0 for all and for tun0:

  - `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/tun0/rp_filter` outputs `0`
  - `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/rp_filter` outputs `0`

When the user establishes a VPN connection with the VPN server two additional routes are pushed to him

```
10.2.0.0/28 via 10.1.0.1 dev tun0 
10.2.0.16/28 via 10.1.0.1 dev tun0
```

the sites have a ccd file with the following contents:

- Site "A":

```
ifconfig-push 10.1.1.1 255.255.0.0
iroute 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.240
```

- Site "B":

```
ifconfig-push 10.1.1.2 255.255.0.0
iroute 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.240
```

My problem is both calls to the site's routers web frontend are directed to the same site. I call:

- https://10.2.0.1/
- https://10.2.0.17/

My guess is that the reverse path needs configuration, but I am lost here. Of course there might already be a problem on the outbound connection.
The connection works fine when the site LANs do have different network addresses.
I guess I could solve the problem, when I would apply SNAT on the site's router, but I would like to keep the configuration at the server.
Any help is very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need different transfer sub network instead of just on ip imho,

Comment: What kind of VPN solution do you use?

Comment: @Turdie I use OpenVPN

Comment: @djdomi What exactly do you mean by "different transfer sub network instead of just on ip"? Could you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: 10.0.1.1 one subnet, and 10.0.2.1 for the other transfernet, else it will be a mess for routing in some rare bugs of software routers